# Maintaining scroll position between page loads with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a novice who understands HTML5 and CSS3 but not JavaScript all that well. I'm trying to keep my browser maintained in the same scroll position while I click between different pages on my site. These pages are illustration.html, design.html and brochures.html. The Jump back to the top each time I load a new page is becoming a little frustrating. So here is an example of my HTML5 below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head> 
                <script src="../js/browser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <section>   
                     <header><title>design</title></header>
                        <article>
                                 <div id="illustration">
                                    <a href="illustration.html">illustration</a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="design">
                                     <a href="#">design</a>
                                 </div>

                                 <div id="brochures">
                                     <a href="brochure.html">brochures</a>
                                </div>
                         </article>
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Is there a simple piece of JavaScript to keep my scroll position in place while clicking between pages?

Comment: It is normal browser behaviour and most users will expect it to jump to the top. Can you show why it is frustrating?

Comment: It's frustrating because I have information that sits in the middle of all three pages. So when I scroll down to the information i want to be able to click to the next page and have it positioned in the same spot rather then having to scroll all the way back down again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Try this, put it just above your closing `</body>` tag for all your pages. Disclaimer: it is just pseudo-code (didn't test it).

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        // See if there is a scroll pos and go there.
        var lastYPos = +localStorage.getItem('scrollYPos');
        if (lastYPos) {
            console.log('Setting scroll pos to:', lastYPos);
            window.scrollTo(0, lastYPos);
        }

        // On navigating away first save the position.
        var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('article a');

        var onNavClick = function() {
            console.log('Saving scroll pos to:', window.scrollY);
            localStorage.setItem('scrollYPos', window.scrollY);
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            anchors[i].addEventListener('click', onNavClick);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

What this is doing in theory:

"When the document is ready check if the browser supports localStorage. If it does check if it has set a scroll position. If it has then scroll to that position."

"If the user clicks a link. Save the position in storage"

Note that you don't even know if the next page is long enough. Also note that this is unusual and ill-advised behaviour.

Comment: This is great it works really well thank you!, I hope I can write JavaScript like this one day.

Comment: Oh great, it is rare that code works first time. One thing is that this checks when elements are ready in the HTML tree but doesn't check if things like images have loaded which can effect the page height - it means it will scroll quickly but could also be inaccurate, if so you could consider waiting for all resources to load with `window.addEventListener('load', function() {` instead of what is there now

Comment: @ Dominic hats off to you brother!!!!

Answer (score 1):

That is going to be tricky, either you save the Scroll position on each scroll event within a cookie/session and set the scroll position to the last known position on the next occurring page load, or you replace your pages through Ajax. Either way, it's not that easy and as already stated in a comment on your question, most users will expect the next page to jump back on top. But it sounds more like you would be interested in a single page layout. See some examples here: http://onepagelove.com/